# How to select last element that don't have specific class?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How can I select last `li` that doesn't have the `.hidden` class?

I have HTML and CSS like this:

```css
ul li:last-child:not(:first-child):not(.hidden) button {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
    <ul>
      <li>
        <button>1</button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button>2</button>
      </li>
      <li class="hidden">
        <button>3</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Do you want to select second li in your example?

Comment: It is not possible.

Comment: Have I made a mistake in figuring out what he actually wanted?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At the current moment, there is no CSS way of being able to find an element that is then followed by another specific element.

Possibly soon, there will be the CSS Relational Pseudo-class `:has()` which will make what you want possible. This is currently in the [CSS Selectors Level 4 Draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational) and looks unlikely to be rolled out across any browsers any time soon.

A demo is below but don't expect it to work until the Selectors 4 Draft is at least in Working Draft.

Keep an eye on [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-has) to see when it becomes readily available.

```css
ul li:has(+ .hidden:last-child),
ul li:last-child:not(.hidden) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <button>1</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button>2</button>
  </li>
  <li class="hidden">
    <button>3</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

`:has()` is available in jQuery though, so here's a jQuery alternative

[Read more here from the Official jQuery Docs](https://api.jquery.com/has/)

```js
$('ul li:has(+ .hidden:last-child), ul li:not(.hidden):last-child').css('background', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <button>1</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button>2</button>
  </li>
  <li class="hidden">
    <button>3</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

The CSS `:nth` and `:last-child` pseudo selectors can only work with **tags** and not other selectors like `:not` or `class` but if there is always going to be only one `.hidden` `li` at the end, then you could use something like this:

```css
li:nth-last-child(2) { background: lightblue; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li class="hidden">3 hidden</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li class="hidden">4 hidden</li>
</ul>
```